# list< T >::iterator or syntax error?

Tags: c++

I'm currently getting the following compile errors:

```
In function 'int main()':
error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
error: missing template arguments before 'i'
error: expected ';' before 'i'
error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
```

I've highlighted the line the first error flags on in the code block below:

```
// test highscoresfilemanager reading & writing
/*
HighScorePair paira("holly", 10);
HighScorePair pairb("carl", 20);
*/
list< HighScorePair > list;
//list.push_back(paira); list.push_back(pairb);
HighScoresFileManager::GetInstance()->ReadFileToList(list);
list< HighScorePair >::iterator i; //ERROR FLAGS HERE ODDLY
for(i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i)
   std::cout << (*i).playerName << " " << (*i).playerScore << std::endl;
```

I left in some commented out text I was using to test something previously because I'm certain that that commented out text works perfectly and if it works I don't see why the new code I've added wouldn't work, I'm not using any new classes or anything, I've just tried to get an iterator setup.

I feel quite rude as I think I'm basically asking someone to check my syntax, I keep reading over it and thinking I must be missing a colon somewhere or something but I just can't see what the issue is! A new eye would be greatly appreciated! I appreciate you might want more code (which I can provide) but like I said if the stuff commented out worked then I *think* the new code should to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call your variable `list`.

Comment: or even better, don't pull `std::list` into the global namespace

Comment: Better still, don't use `std::list` at all, under any name.

Comment: @JerryCoffin a time and a place for everything

Comment: @SethCarnegie: `std::list` may be a step above bogosort, but only a small one. Bjarne has done some benchmarking and even in the cases that *should* favor `std::list`, it's still slower than a vector -- usually by quite a wide margin.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: no. A time and a place for everything *useful*. That said, legitimate usecases for `std::list` do exist. In cases where performance is irrelevant, and you need the guarantees offered specifically by `std::list` (such as neither pointers or iterators being invalidated if you insert elements)

Comment: @Jerry - If you have a vector with a few hundred thousand entries and you need to insert a new element in the middle, you may need a huge allocation and will certainly need to copy a large number of elements.  Inserting into a linked list has no such problem.  Linear seek operations for a long list will be very slow, but a binary search of a sorted list may be bearable.  For non-trivial collections with frequent insert/delete operations a list may be the best choice.  Particularly if random seek operations are infrequent.

Comment: @JerryCoffin a good use for `std::list` is when you need to insert elements in the middle of the container without invalidating iterators. @jalf no, I obviously meant _literally everything_.

Comment: @MichaelJ: Strangely, that's exactly the sort of test Bjarne did, where `list` consistently lost (badly).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I can also manufacture tests wherein `list` wins by a large margin.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: If you work hard enough, you probably can. Do you honestly think Bjarne has a reason to do something like that though? If so, what would it be? As far as invalidating iterators goes, technically you're correct. In reality, on the rare (and it really is rare, IME) occasion that you need this capability, you can define an iterator-like class for a vector that stores a pointer to the vector plus an index. That will be larger than a normal iterator, but still normally saves quite a bit of space compared to a list (with two extra pointers per node).

Comment: @Jerry -- I don't know what tests he did, but in normal usage with large data sets a list will be more efficient than a vector if there are large numbers of inserts and deletes.  Do you have a reference to the tests to which you refer?

Comment: @MichaelJ: [His talk from Going native 2012](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style). Sorry, I don't have a time-stamp handy, but it's well worth watching the whole thing anyway. Doing some looking, start from page 45 of [his slides](http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/events/GoingNative12/GN12Cpp11Style.pdf).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I don't really know how storing an index would be better than storing a pointer. And I've had to have such a container (where inserts don't invalidate iterators) on multiple occasions. But anyways.

Comment: @Jerry -- I watched the talk.  It was quite interesting.  Dr Stroustrup explains the vector/list problem very well.  Basically, when performing an insertion or deletion, the time to seek to the target location is much larger than the time to perform the insert/delete operation.  Seeking with a vector is much faster than a list (due to much more indirection with the list), therefore the insertion/deletion for the vector finishes up being faster.  (continued ...)

Comment: (... Continued) 
  Also, the vector data, being sequential, gives a lot of cache hits, while the list nodes tend to be spread out into different memory areas leading to a lot more page faults.  The argument is convincing for the general case.  There may be exceptions, e.g. complex objects with complicated copy constructors, but I need to think about that a bit more.  Note that Dr Stroustrup did not say "never use a list" but rather "be aware of the overheads when deciding what container to use".

Comment: guys, please discuss this somewhere else, this is completely offtopic (I don't even understand what's to discuss here, lists obvibously have legal use cases).

Answer (score 3):

First, I'm supposing that you've got a `using namespace std;` somewhere;
that's generally not a good idea.  But the basic problem would remain
(albeit not for `list`, since you'd write `std::list): you've defined a
local variable with the same name as a symbol in a larger scope; the
local variable hides that symbol from its point of declaration until it
goes out of scope.  So up until the line:

```
list< HighScorePair> list;
```

, `list` refers to the symbol you pulled into global scope with `using
namespace std;`, and after that line, until the end of the block, it
refers to the variable you have just defined here.  The variable is 
**not** a template, and its type doesn't support `<`, so `list <` isn't
legal.

As a general rule, I would recommend against hiding names.  It leads to
confusion.  Also: type names should be unqualified nouns (like `list`),
variable names should be qualified nouns (like `currentList`).  At least
in principle; I can see cases where such a rule would be overkill.

Comment: would you please explain what you mean by unqualified and qualified? that'd be much appreciated :) my teacher said as a rule of thumb own types can more easily be identified with capital letters, and i tend to use camel case for variables but i'm open to suggestions. and yeah i put the namespace in for clarity but i understand its not the best approach and i probably wouldnt if the project were any larger. Also thanks for identifying the problem for me, which i entirely understand now:)

Comment: @Holly What's qualified or unqualified depends somewhat on context, but something like "state" would be unqualified, where as "currentState" or "newState" would be qualified.  As a general rule, types are unqualified nouns, variables and constants qualified nouns and functions verbs.  In practice, I find this rule too general to be 100% reliable, however.  And in order to parse C++, you have know what is a type, and what isn't.  My personal rule is that type names start with a capital, all others with a small letter.  But any rule that distinguishes types is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you wrote `using namespace std;` When you call variable that associate with function in std:: it will throw compile error. Just use exact namespace when define variables ( std::list ).